# Django - Static Files from App Directories

Tags: python, django, static-files, django-settings

In a development environment, I'd like to use static files from the app directories.

```
#settings.py

SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = (os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static_files/'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
#...
  'django.core.context_processors.static',
#...
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
#...
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#...
)
```

I can find my static file if located in `/static/css/file.css` but not if in `an_app/static/css/file.css`.

Comment: Read this carefully and check if you missed something: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development

Comment: It has been read multiple times. Here I have the finder `AppDirectoriesFinder` activated but `manage.py findstatic` doesn't not seem to search into apps/static directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, I made an oversight that was not visible in my question. I was searching into  in `static/js`, `static/flash`, `static/css`, `static/images` and put the files directly into `app/static` so they were not found.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS.
Add a print in your setting file.

Comment: I have intentionally put a syntax error somewhere and the dump seems to have the good values `STATIC_ROOT '/home/glide/Documents/django/cbox/static_files/'` and `STATICFILES_DIRS ('/home/glide/Documents/django/cbox/static/',)` (cbox is the name of the project)